# Convert OUTER APPLY to Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, lateral-join

I have MSSQL Server script that I need to convert to Redshift

Here is part of script

```
 OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 7149 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS CslId,
                MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 9736 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS LearnId,
                MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 9735 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS PMId,
                MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 10299 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS UpSell
        FROM    public.billing_codes_custom_tag ctt 
        WHERE   ctt.customcodeid = bcc.id
                AND ctt.codetagid IN(7149,9736,9735,10299)
        ) AS codeLabel
```

I have error

> '(', ',', , , , AT, CROSS, EXCEPT, FETCH, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTERSECT, ISNULL, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, MINUS, NATURAL, NOTNULL, OFFSET, OPERATOR, ORDER, RIGHT, UNION, WHERE or '[' expected, got 'OUTER'

at this row `OUTER APPLY`

How I can convert this stuff to Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation:

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ctt.customcodeid, 
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 7149 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS CslId,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 9736 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS LearnId,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 9735 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS PMId,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 10299 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS UpSell
     FROM public.billing_codes_custom_tag ctt 
     WHERE ctt.codetagid IN (7149, 9736, 9735, 10299)
     GROUP BY ctt.customcodeid
    ) codeLabel
    ON codeLabel.customcodeid = bcc.id
```

Answer (score -1):

As OUTER APPLY is same as LEFT JOIN

I rewrite it like this

```
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 7149 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS CslId,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 9736 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS LearnId,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 9735 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS PMId,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ctt.codetagid = 10299 THEN Id ELSE 0 END) AS UpSell
    FROM    public.billing_codes_custom_tag ctt 
    WHERE   ctt.customcodeid = bcc.id
            AND ctt.codetagid IN(7149,9736,9735,10299)
    ) AS codeLabel
```

Comment: This is incorrect. In `LEFT JOIN` you cannot access the left-hand side query operators, e.g. `bcc.id` in this case