# Outer apply to left join conversion

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query in SQL Server that I'm trying to migrate to redshift. It has `OUTER APPLY` in it but Redshift doesn't support it. How can I convert it to `left join` so that I can use it in Redshift?

```
....
OUTER APPLY
( 
    SELECT TOP 1 fel.*
    FROM fact.FactEventLog fel 
    WHERE fpt.ParcelProfileKey = fel.ParcelProfileKey
            AND
            fpt.LastEventKey = fel.EventLegKey
            AND
            FPT.DateLastEvent = fel.EventDateTimeUTC
) fel
....
```

Something answered in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199438/convert-outer-apply-to-redshift) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040915/rewrite-outer-apply-to-redshift-with-subquery)

Comment: What does TOP 1 mean without ORDER BY? What column(s) from inside the apply do you actually need in the outer query? Are they for output, later filtering, both? It’s hard to tell what the query does when you’ve left out most of it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You can ignore it ig. It doesn't affect the question and it's not a compulsion to use ORDER BY.

Comment: well you can use an analytic row number() and partition it then limit to row number 1... but w/o an order by.... kinda needed or the outer apply isn't.  if the limits of the sub query limit to 1 and only 1 record each time; then why not just use a inner/left join?

Comment: Well it does matter because if you change it to a join you need to find some way to deterministically define which row you get and which rows you discard. Join doesn’t have the luxury of saying “TOP but I don’t care which one” the way apply does.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Question is a little variation of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199438/convert-outer-apply-to-redshift

Comment: @AaronBertrand or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040915/rewrite-outer-apply-to-redshift-with-subquery

Comment: “It’s a little variation on this other thing over here” isn’t how this site works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe.... someting like...

```
....
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT fel.*, row_number() over (partition by ParcelProfileKey, EventLegKey, EventDateTimeUTC order by null) RN
        FROM fact.FactEventLog fel 
    ) fel
      on fpt.ParcelProfileKey = fel.ParcelProfileKey
     AND fpt.LastEventKey = fel.EventLegKey
     AND fpt.DateLastEvent = fel.EventDateTimeUTC 
     AND 1=fel.RN

....
```

but it just seems so wrong w/o an order by actually defined in the window function.  it's like you don't care what random result is returned just so long as 1 exists... but then why not use an exists.... *shrug*

Comment: Also if redshift doesn’t even support apply I have to wonder about window function support. It might be fine but also it might be a migration involving a neverending stream of roadblocks.

Comment: True: but it appears supported: though version's not defined: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: But then the next query, and the query after that… :-)

Comment: Totally agree.  One can't eat an elephant in one bite so you don't know until you get into the weeds and then you find the poison pill/piece or you don't.

Comment: @xQbert There is a select clause where fel is used. It is giving null value. `.....fel.CarrierEventDescription...`

Comment: @Notyetdecided Yep. Left join could do that. Meaning fpt has a record fel does not (or the value's just null). So... should it be left Join? or inner Join? or are you missing data in fel?  The "Outer Apply" made me think you needed a left  which is why I used it.  I take it you're saying the original data set didn't have this problem.  So that could be a function of the order by picking the "wrong" record to be 1st too... I'd need to see sample data on the left and right side which meet the join criteria to see what's going on.  Keep i mind top w/o an order by could return iconsistent results

Comment: what I provided is pseudo code results could vary each run depending on how the compiler organizes the data since we don't have an order by.  The NULL description could be be caused by wrong ordered data or missing data.  You'd need to provide all records from fel matching the join criteria where it's missing.  If Fell has 5 records and 1 of them has description and others don't, if the populated one is 1st (by compiler choice) , it would work, otherwise not.  If there simply is no such record in fel, then yeah it's blank by design due to missing data. I've insufficient information to know Why